# Customize Editor Styles

Tags: editor, visual-editor

I know there are plugins that do this, but since my needs are so small, I'm hoping there's another solution...

I want to edit the `<hr />` style in the WordPress editor to have `clear: both;`. Is there a way to do this in the functions.php or something?

Comment: This sort of thing is best done with CSS. Just add the necessary CSS rule to the `style.css` in your theme folder (`/wp-content/themes/theme-name/`).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dalbeab already answered your question, but thought I would point out a way to add horizontal rule to your editor if you wish.

Within `functions.php`, you can add this:

```
// add horizontal rule button
function enable_more_buttons($buttons) {
    $buttons[] = 'hr';
    return $buttons;
}
add_filter('mce_buttons', 'enable_more_buttons');
```

Then you will have a TinyMCE button that looks like this which will let you add an `<hr />` with only 1 click:

[image]

Comment: Actually @dalbeab's answer didn't work.

Comment: You are talking about editor styles as opposed to the styles the end user sees? In that case you want to look at: [Function Reference/add editor style « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style)